# How to find the index of an array inside a list

Tags: python, numpy

Assume that you have a list of arrays. And then you separately specify one (which is also present inside the list). How can you get its index ?

```
In [185]: y_train.index(Y_test[0])
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-185-c9084f698632> in <module>()
 ----> 1 y_train.index(Y_test[0])
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Here, `y_train` is the 'big' list containing everything, and `Y_test[0]` is one of its elements

Comment: Rather than verbally explaining what `counts_train` and `X_test` contain, actual code that shows how the example data are stored in those variables would better clarify your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(0, len(y_train)):
 for j in range(0, len(Y_test)):
     if y_train[i].shape==Y_test[j].shape:
        v= y_train[i]==Y_test[j]
        if v.all():
           print ('i',i)
           print ('j',j)
```

This find the indexes that I am after. The error comes from the fact that it is not clear what the truth value should be when working ambiguously with arrays of multiple elements